# pythonのmatplotlibでベクトルの描写を更新する際、軸の設定はそのままにデータだけを更新したい

Tags: python, matplotlib

python3.5を使っています。matplotlibを使ってベクトルのアニメーションを作成したいです。下のコードではTimerを使って一定時間ごとに描写しなおしています。しかし、アニメーションの負担を小さくするために、軸の設定をいちいち再設定し直さずに、ベクトルの値のみを更新したいです。どのようにコードを直せばよいのでしょうか。

---

**表示されるGUI**
[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg \
    import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.t=0
        self.angle=30
        self.delta1=0
        self.delta2=0

        self.figure=plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=80)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes.set_aspect("equal")
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updatePlot)
        self.timer.start(10) # msec

        self.setWindowTitle("Plot")
        self.show()

    def updatePlot(self):
        w=1
        self.t = self.t+0.05
        self.axes.clear()        
        phi=self.angle*np.pi/180
        
        X1=0
        Y1=0
        delta1=self.delta1*np.pi/180
        d1=np.sin(w*self.t-delta1)
        U1=d1*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(phi)
        V1=d1*np.cos(phi)*np.cos(phi)
        
        X2=0
        Y2=0
        delta2=self.delta2*np.pi/180
        d2=np.sin(w*self.t-delta2)
        U2=d2*np.cos(np.pi/2-phi)*np.cos(np.pi-phi)
        V2=d2*np.cos(np.pi/2-phi)*np.sin(np.pi-phi)

        X3=0
        Y3=0
        U3=U1+U2
        V3=V1+V2
        
        self.axes.quiver(X1,Y1,U1,V1,angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,color="r")
        self.axes.quiver(X2,Y2,U2,V2,angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,color="b") 
        self.axes.quiver(X3,Y3,U3,V3,angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,color="m")
        
        self.axes.set_xlim(-1.2,1.2)
        self.axes.set_ylim(-1.2,1.2)
        self.axes.grid("on")
        self.axes.set_title("Plot",fontsize=12)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x",size=15)        
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y",size=15)

        self.canvas.draw() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",15) 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの記事を参考に、グラフ領域を描く処理とベクトル描画の処理を分離し、ベクトルデータ設定の前に、以前に描いたデータを全て削除して常に1組のデータしか存在しないようにすることで実現できます。
[In Matplotlib, how can I clear an axes' contents without erasing its axis labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43075614/9014308)
回答のオプション2をそのまま使います。

> ```
> # option 2, remove all lines and collections
> for artist in plt.gca().lines + plt.gca().collections:
>     artist.remove()
> ```

全体はこうなります。`####`でコメントした部分が変更点です。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg \
    import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.t=0
        self.angle=30
        self.delta1=0
        self.delta2=0

        self.figure=plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=80)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes.set_aspect("equal")
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.drawGrid() #### グラフ領域を描く処理を呼び出し

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updatePlot)
        self.timer.start(10) # msec

        self.setWindowTitle("Plot")
        self.show()

    def updatePlot(self):
        w=1
        self.t = self.t+0.05
        #### self.axes.clear() # 削除してdrawGrid()に移動
        phi=self.angle*np.pi/180
        
        X1=0
        Y1=0
        delta1=self.delta1*np.pi/180
        d1=np.sin(w*self.t-delta1)
        U1=d1*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(phi)
        V1=d1*np.cos(phi)*np.cos(phi)
        
        X2=0
        Y2=0
        delta2=self.delta2*np.pi/180
        d2=np.sin(w*self.t-delta2)
        U2=d2*np.cos(np.pi/2-phi)*np.cos(np.pi-phi)
        V2=d2*np.cos(np.pi/2-phi)*np.sin(np.pi-phi)

        X3=0
        Y3=0
        U3=U1+U2
        V3=V1+V2

        #### 描かれている内容のデータを削除することで再描画させない
        for artist in plt.gca().lines + plt.gca().collections:
            artist.remove()

        self.axes.quiver(X1,Y1,U1,V1,angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,color="r")
        self.axes.quiver(X2,Y2,U2,V2,angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,color="b") 
        self.axes.quiver(X3,Y3,U3,V3,angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,color="m")

        #### グラフ領域を描いている部分を削除してdrawGrid()に移動

        self.canvas.draw() 

    #### グラフ領域を描く処理を定義
    def drawGrid(self):
        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.set_xlim(-1.2,1.2)
        self.axes.set_ylim(-1.2,1.2)
        self.axes.grid("on")
        self.axes.set_title("Plot",fontsize=12)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x",size=15)
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y",size=15)

        self.canvas.draw() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",15) 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: とても素早い回答ありがとうございます！アニメーションがかなり早く描写できるようになりました。